# Como trazer informações ao clicar na dataGridView C#, E somar valores de uma coluna

Tags: c#, winforms

Ola estou com dificuldade para criar um consulta de uma gridview usei entity Framework
Bom, tenho uma gridView ela carrega os Dados normalmente [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No TextBox abaixo quero pega o nome da pessoa que esta selecionada colocar no campo e no grid onde ta o numero de paginas quero somar o total e colocar no textBox Total impressão/mes  referente ao nome selecionado no campo
esse é o codigo que carrega o GridView:

```
private void ler_Impressora()
{
        ImpressoraEntities context = new ImpressoraEntities();
        IEnumerable<Tmp_Printlog> lista = from p in context.Tmp_Printlog select p;
        dgvLista.DataSource = lista.ToList();
}
```

Comment: QUANDO é que queres que essa informação apareça? Quando clicas numa célula na gridview? Sugiro que essa lista fique disponível na classe para poderes pesquisar a adicionar a informação que queres.

Comment: Ola, quero pegar  o campo que está selecionado ou foi clicado colocar o nome do usuário no textbox usuário   e no textbox  total impressão colocar a soma total de impressão(paginas) que ele fez.

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar o evento **CellClick** ou **CellContentClick** ou qualquer outro evento de click da dataGridView.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
        int Total = 0;
        var Row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;

        txtUsuario.Text = Row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow linha in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (linha.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == txtUsuario.Text)
            {
                Total += int.Parse(linha.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            }
        }


        txtTotal.Text = Total.ToString();
 }
```

- Na variavel Row peguei a linha selecionada.
- Depois peguei o nome do usuário.
- E após isso percorri toda a dataGridView comparando o usuário selecionado com o usuário da dataGridView, e somei as paginas impressas.
- E por fim coloquei a soma no TextBox total.